# Android - specific twitter hashtag newsfeed/timeline

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-fabric

I'm attempting to create an **Android Twitter timeline that shows tweets for a specific hashtag**; i.e. #soccer. So far all results seem to be PHP, JSON and other languages that do not apply to Android.

*IS there any library API out there that does this for Android?*

*If not, what's the next best thing I could do?*

Thanks!

Comment: If you are developing Android app in Java, the `twitter4j` library is useful to retrieve tweets. You can search or stream in tweets. Works very well with Android

Comment: Thanks Sameer! Do you know where I could examine specific examples?
Also, do you think Twitters new Fabric plugin and Twitter4j would work together? i.e. Fabric for Sign In; Twitter4j for a Tweet live stream? thanks in advance.

Comment: Twitter4j examples can be found here: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html. Sorry, I have no idea for twitter4j integration with Fabric. But I would suggest getting your hands on twitter4j to get insight.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter kit can be used to make RESTful API calls. These can be used directly in the Android code.

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/api